# how to create bar under component?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am developing a flutter app, I need to create a navigation bar like this

[image]

the problem is I don't know how to add that bar under categories (which changes to red when the component is selected).

any idea?

Comment: Tabbar. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html#material.TabBar.1

Comment: what about the search text field can I add it to the app bar also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TabBar` and `TabBarView`.
you can change UI the way you like.

**Demo result**

[image]

**demo Widget**

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatelessWidgetState createState() => _MyStatelessWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatelessWidgetState extends State<MyStatelessWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final tabs = <Widget>[
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined),
    ),
    Tab(
      icon: Text("second tab"),
    ),
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_5_sharp),
    ),
  ];
  late final TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TabController(length: tabs.length, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              filled: true,
              suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.more),
            ),
          ],
          bottom: TabBar(controller: controller, tabs: tabs),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: controller,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text("It's cloudy here"),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text("It's rainy here"),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text("It's sunny here"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error when i initialize controller (The argument type '_TabsScreenState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TickerProvider'.)

Comment: check if the state is using mixing `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` like `class _MyStatelessWidgetState extends State<MyStatelessWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {`

also check your flutter version is updated.